# Java Generics - inserting inner type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I am new to java. I am just trying to pass `Comparable<String>` into a method parameter of generic type `<E extends Comparable<E>>` . I believe the meaning of `<E extends Comparable<E>>` is any object that extends `Comparable`. Please let me know how to pass `Comparable<String>` or any object that extends `Comparable<String>` and has an other object in it.

Compiler is giving me error `The inferred type Compare<String> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>>`

### Code:

```
public class Compare<T> implements Comparable<T>{

    public int compareTo(T o) {

        return 0; // Not worried about logic

    }

}

class CompareTest{

    public <E extends Comparable<E>>void testGeneric(E e){

        System.out.println("Executed");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Compare<String> compare = new Compare<String>();

        CompareTest test = new CompareTest();
        test.testGeneric(compare);
        //The inferred type Compare<String> is not a valid substitute for the bounded
        //parameter <E extends Comparable<E>>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`E extends Comparable<E>` means: a type E that is able to compare to other objects of the same type E.

But your Compare type doesn't qualify. It can't compare with another Compare. A `Compare<T>` can only compare itself to a `T`, and not to a `Compare<T>`, since it's declared as

```
public class Compare<T> implements Comparable<T>
```

It's quite hard to understand what you want to achieve with this Compare type.

Comment: I was just practicing the notion `< E extends Comparable`< E `> `> . I though If I pass an object like new Comparable<String>() it would accept as It Comparable`< Strinng `> extends Comparable. Not sure where am I missing.

Answer (score 2):

Your method

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> void testGeneric(E e){
```

expects a type `E` that is a sub type of `Comparable<E>`. But you are passing it a `Compare<String>` which is not a sub type of `<Comparable<Compare<String>>`, but a sub type of `Comparable<String>`.

You'll have to clarify what you are trying to do if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

The error in my IDE says:

```
Inferred type 'Compare<java.lang.String>' for type parameter 'E' is not within its bound; 
should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<Compare<java.lang.String>>'
```

It seems that `E` is inferred as `Compare<String>` instead of `String`.  To get `E` to be `String`, try this:

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> void testGeneric(Comparable<E> e){
```

Comment: it worked like a heaven. I was expecting `< E extends Comparable`< E `> `>  to expect Compare`< String `>  and match Compare `< String `> . I have no clue how come                                    Compare`< String `> = new Compare `< String `>();                  is being treated                               Comparable`<Compare`<String`>`>                               instead of Compare`< String `>

Answer (score 1):

To define a class as being comparable, the generic parameter to `Comparable` must be the class itself:

```
public class MyComparable implements Comparable<MyComparable> {
    public int compareTo(MyComparable o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Applying that to your class, you get the following code (which compiles):

```
public static class Compare<T> implements Comparable<Compare<T>> {
    public int compareTo(Compare<T> o) {
        return 0; // Not worried about logic
    }
}

class CompareTest {
    public <E extends Comparable<E>> void testGeneric(E e) {
        System.out.println("Executed");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compare<String> compare = new Compare<String>();
    CompareTest test = new CompareTest();
    test.testGeneric(compare);
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. It was the problem of being able to create an object of type you created in the seconds code block. i.e. MyComparable `< MyComparable `< MyComparable so on and on ... `> `>   . Can't we create an object of class MyComparable in the second block. If so an example of that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have simplified my answer for clarity and provided you with a repaired (ie compilable) version of your code.